# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

this is my app.js
Have I defined the items correctly?
I think I did my job right! In accordance with the vuex document

```js
import store from "./store";
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
import vuetify from "./vuetify";
import router from "./router";
import AppComponent from "./components/AppComponent";
import Store from  "./store"
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify,
  router,
  Store,
  components:{
    "app-component":AppComponent,
  }
});
```

this is my store.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from  'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

const departmentRoute= [
  { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: 'مدیریت  مطالبات   ' ,link:'demands'},
  { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: 'مدیریت  گزارشات   ' ,link:'reports'},
];
const SuperAdminRoute= [
  { icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline', text: '  مدیریت کاربران ' ,link:'users'},
  { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: 'مدیریت  مطالبات   ' ,link:'demands'},
  { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: 'مدیریت  گزارشات   ' ,link:'reports'},
  { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: 'آمار و ارقام     ' ,link:'demands'},
];
const studentRoute= [
  { icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline', text: 'آخرین مطالبات به رای گذاشته شده' ,link:'selfDemand'},
  { icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline', text: 'مطالبات من  ' ,link:'selfDemand'},
  { icon: 'mdi-account-badge-outline', text: ' پیگیری مطالبه   ' ,link:'addReport'},
  { icon: 'mdi-checkbox-marked-circle-outline', text: 'تایید حساب کاربری' ,link:'verify'},
];
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    level: localStorage.getItem('role')
  },
  getters: {
    items: state => {
      switch (state.level) {
        case "super-admin":
          return SuperAdminRoute;
        case "department":
          return departmentRoute;
        default:
          return studentRoute;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and this is my app component script:

```html
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: "MainDashboard",
  props: {
      source: String,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['items'])
  },
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null,
    title:'فاد | فارغ التحصیلی ناد',
  }),
  methods:{
    logout() {
      axios.post('/api/logout').then(res=>{
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        localStorage.removeItem('role');
        this.$router.push('/login');
      }).catch(err=>{
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

when i use map getters in my componenet i can get my getters in vuex tab but i can't get it in component computed property !
why ?
How can I troubleshoot?Could this error be due to invalid import vuex ?

Vuex Tab :

[image]

component :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### i changed this line from

```
import Store from  "./store"
```

to :

```
import store from  "./store"
```

and my problem was solved !

Answer (score 1):

You must use store in app.js or main.js like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
  store
}).$mount("#app");
```

if you use like `import {store} from "./store";` you get this error.

Comment: plz show your code of use computed entire html??